# Javascript name clash?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a function that looks exactly like this:

```
function exportSelectedToExcel(id)
{
    var selectedRows = new Array();

    //Retrieve selected items from the grid
    selectedRows = grid.getGridParam('selarrrow');

    //Always add the item in id, it doesn't matter if it's there twice.
    selectedRows[selectedRows.length] = id;

    //Build the url
    var params = selectedRows.join("&id="); 
    var exportUrl = "/Export/SelectListExporters?id=" + params;

    //Show the selection form
    SelectionWindow.show(exportUrl, "#selectionForm", 400);
}
```

Everytime I run this function the array grows with at least one item (the one i add to the end of it). This must surely mean that I have another array somewhere else in the system with the same name, right?

Is there any way in google chrome or firefox to find out where that variable is?

EDIT: There is no such variable in the whole project, verified from within visual studio.

EDIT 2: This is what I'm calling: http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0fb79d.htm

EDIT 3: I've changed the code to start with the following:

```
var retrievedRows = grid.getGridParam('selarrrow');
var selectedRows = retrievedRows.slice(0);
```

Now it works like intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code can be simplified to:

```
var selectedRows = grid.getGridParam('selarrrow');
selectedRows.push(id);
```

Looking at this it becomes obvious that `grid.getGridParam()` (whatever it is) is the cause of the problem. Debug this (possibly by printing `selectedRows`) and investigate it.

`selectedRows` is declared locally inside a function, so even if there is a global variables named the same, it will not affect your function.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call the function, the array is:

- Scoped to the function
- Overwritten with an empty array

So:

> Everytime I run this function the array grows with at least one item (the one i add to the end of it). This must surely mean that I have another array somewhere else in the system with the same name, right?

No.

Since you then overwrite the array again (which makes creating the array with `new Array()` nothing more than a waste of bandwidth and cycles) with `selectedRows = grid.getGridParam('selarrrow');`, it is most likely that which is growing.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but how on earth can I affect the return value of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebug plugin for Firefox might help you out:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/

With Firebug you can live debug your Javascript variables in your webpage.